# How can I add an error to specific commands discord.py

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py

I want to have errors for each command, instead of using an error event which can't be specific and troubleshoot a command that may need extra help given to the user. Is there a way I can put an error onto a command?

```py
@client.command(aliases=['translate', 'translator'])
async def trans(ctx, lang=None, *, args=None):

    t = Translator()
    a = t.translate(args, dest=lang)

    if lang == None:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, please use a Valid destination language. You can view them with ``&languages``')
        return

    if args == None:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, please provide a message in English to translate!``')
        return

    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
            embed = discord.Embed(title="API Error!", description=f"{ctx.author.mention}, google translate's API is bugged, this command could fix by sending it another time", color=0xE74C3C)
            message = await ctx.message.channel.send(embed=embed, delete_after=20)
```

Comment: nope, you have to put it in the error handler

Comment: But how can I make an error message for each command if you make a mistake?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it like that, you have to use an error handler

```py
@bot.command()
async def some_command_name(ctx):
    # ...


@some_command_name.error # ← name of the command + .error
async def some_command_name_error(ctx, error):
    # Handle all the errors for a command here
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        await ctx.send("API error")
```